# Total number of combinations

Tags: combinations

I need a bit of help with combinations with yes or no answers - and would like to check that I have worked this out correctly.

Let's say I have a hotdog stand.

If I have 6 different types of sausage as option 1, 3 different types of bread roll as option 2 and 3 different types of onion as option 3  - would I be correct in saying that to find out the amount of combinations of hotdog possible I simply multiply 6x3x3 to get 54

If this is true, and if my next options have yes or no answers how do I factor these into the combinations equation, let's go with 5 different types of sauce where you have a choice of yes or no for each sauce and 6 different coloured napkins where again you can choose yes or no for each napkin.

Would the complete equation be 6x3x3x2^5x2^6 and would the answer be 110,592

thanks :)

Comment: Well...some people don't like onions, so maybe that should be $4$ onion options (to include a "no onion" choice).  Similarly, maybe people don't want the bread.  But you are correct if you require a Sausage-Bread-Onion triple.

Comment: This is the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). To gain intuition for why it works, think about simpler examples with smaller numbers and write out all the possibilities.